# ASP.NET Temporary or Session Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

What would be the proper syntax in ASP.NEt 3.5 C# to assign a TextBox value to a temporary or session variable to be manipulated (added, subtracted, multiplied, divided) at different points in the application? I want to add a decimal number to this variable in almost every instance as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Session["MyValue"] = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);

decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["MyValue"]);
```

is this what you want?

Comment: Session["MyValue"] = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text); Thats a bad practice you should not have used conversion to decimal here anyway its going to to be converted in Object form

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
Session["decimalnumber"] = 1 //Your value

decimal number = (decimal)Session["decimalnumber"]
```

This assigns 1 into a session variable - then gets it back out as an decimal

Answer (score 1):

if you want the value of the textbox at different point of the application then session is best choice. so value of the textbox give to the session variable. and when u want that value then convert it to the decimal and the use that session variable...

```
Session["SessionVariableName"] = txtpass.Text;
decimal VariableName = (decimal)Session["SessionVariableName"];
//Or 
decimal VariableName = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["SessionVariableName"]);
```

Hope this will helps you....